# rotate error log file of MySQL 8.0 server over windows

Tags: mysql, windows, error-log

we have MySQL 8.0 installed over windows and my err log file (.err) is very large (11 GB),

so we need to rotate the error loge so it writes to a new file when the current file is 200 MB

we tried to rename the error log file but it needs to stop MySQL service.

so is there a way to rotate error log file automatically like audit file rotating

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-rotation.html

Comment: Hi @Luuk MySQL server is over windows and rename command don't work as mysqld service is always  writing in the err file so rename command fails

Comment: did you try `mysqladmin flush-logs` ?

Comment: Hi @Luuk yes, but no effect plus we need this error logs to investigate server issues, all we need is to start to write in new err file when the current err log file is 200 MB

Comment: @GalalRamzy A specific suggestion from MySQL for renaming log BEFORE the flush is a part of - .  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-rotation.html

Comment: This url may also be of interest to you in accomplishing the rename of existing 11GB error log.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html  Read the entire content, please.